# Adding and Subtracting Powers of 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

I am entirely new to this subject and am already lost. The problem is Five x Ten to the power of Negative Two, + Four x Ten to the power of Negative Three. I was told that I have to make the exponents the same, and to do that I had to move one of the decimals, so I made Four x Ten to negative Two into 40 x Ten to negative Two. My final answer was 45 x 10 to the negative Two. Is this correct? If not how do I do this?

Comment: $5 \times 10^{-2} + 4\times 10^{-3}$ can be produced with: `$5 \times 10^{-2} + 4\times 10^{-3}$` - the dollar signs surround mathematical code expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Five x Ten to the power of Negative Two, + Four x Ten to the power of Negative Three

... is a lot easier if you know the notation:

$$5 \times 10^{-2} + 4\times 10^{-3}$$

[And you should realize that $10^{-3}$ is less than $10^{-2}$. In fact $10^{-3} = 0.001$ and $10^{-2} = 0.01$.]

Then you can adjust the power-of-ten multipliers to get them the same, using for example

$$10^{-2} = 10 \times 10^{-3}$$

so

\begin{align}5
 \times 10^{-2} + 4\times 10^{-3} &= 5 \times 10 \times 10^{-3} + 4\times 10^{-3} \\
&= 50 \times 10^{-3} + 4\times 10^{-3} \\
&= 54 \times 10^{-3}  \\
&= 5.4 \times 10^{-2}
\end{align}

So no. Your answer is not correct, and there are two problems, at least. First, it's way too big, and second, it doesn't match up with your problem statements. Probably because you're trying to keep track of this in words rather than numerical layout.

Comment: Joffan how would this differ if one exponent was negative and the other was positive, and with Multiplication and Division?

Comment: it wouldn't really differ a lot. $10^0=1$, in case you didn't realize, so we slide naturally up and down the exponent value dividing or multiplying by $10$ as we go. $10 =10^1 = 10\times 10^0$ and $1=10^0= 10\times 10^{-1}$.

Comment: $10^a10^b = 10^{a+b} $ whether a and b are positive or negative.  So if a < b no matter what the signs, you can always do $10^b = (10^{b-a})\times 10^a $.   Example.  For $6\times10^3 - 4\times 10^{-2}=6\times 10^{5}\times 4\times 10^{-2}=(600000-4 l\times 10^{-2}=599996\times 10^{-2}=5999.96$